# Как отправить сгенерированную картинку в BOTS LONG POLL API на Java

Tags: java, файлы, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

```
            String msg = message.getText();
            MessagesMethods method = vk.messages;
            if(msg.startsWith("/мемс ")) {
                String mem = msg.substring(5);
                method.send()
                        .setPeerId(message.getPeerId())
                        .setMessage("test")
                        .addPhoto(Util.getFile(mem))
                        .execute();
            }
```

код отправки выше

Util:

```
private static BufferedImage getImage(String msg) {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    Font stringFont = new Font( "SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 50 );
    g.setFont(stringFont);
    g.drawString(msg, 0, 400);

    return bufferedImage;
}
public static File getFile(String msg) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\image.png");
    try {
        boolean b = ImageIO.write(getImage(msg), "png", file);
        System.out.println("Картинка создана: " + b);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Не удалось создать изображение!");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return file;
}
```

Вылетает ошибка при написании /мемс (любое слово)

09:49:42.086 [main] DEBUG api.longpoll.bots.methods.impl.VkMethod - <-- 182ms: 200 {"error":{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"Unknown error occurred","request_params":[{"key":"method","value":"photos.saveMessagesPhoto"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"v","value":"5.131"},{"key":"photo","value":"[{"markers_restarted":true,"photo":"c6fdd94d21:x","sizes":[],"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"kid":"82e988b3bbfb73e63b83f80762302082","sizes2":[["s","73dc81fbd5359841bcc8485750db278e02bb8fe98677c140e1d6f707","-5032855809629860884",75,75],["m","81a13caa0d81699b8b92bdfd6027a723feea07086c05af56f617748c","-7038935191574522449",130,130],["x","e8fe23611f5b0a924badfea624cc519523caba55f7c5589d8c7d00c4","-332785084712083935",400,400],["o","81a13caa0d81699b8b92bdfd6027a723feea07086c05af56f617748c","-7038935191574522449",130,130],["p","459ec95276a68484db5c611328c03e1d4655ec169fec641bc4fcd6a8","-4687761155108231590",200,200],["q","3f12b4aa8c4b0fb78dde284af4ff3d51b5aa136a93eebe72f3c978ee","8043980158561383550",320,320],["r","3664d209b2246ff89ef95e2b2c6f7dcf52cbc05aed35bd02f6a3ac4f","6410948086168719709",400,400]],"urls":[],"urls2":["c9yB-9U1mEG8yEhXUNsnjgK7j-mGd8FA4db3Bw/7EtAbU60J7o.jpg","gaE8qg2BaZuLkr39YCenI_7qBwhsBa9W9hd0jA/r1U0tbytUJ4.jpg","6P4jYR9bCpJLrf6mJMxRlSPKulX3xVidjH0AxA/IR4wh7q1Yfs.jpg","gaE8qg2BaZuLkr39YCenI_7qBwhsBa9W9hd0jA/r1U0tbytUJ4.jpg","RZ7JUnamhITbXGETKMA-HUZV7Baf7GQbxPzWqA/Wibm9RC68b4.jpg","PxK0qoxLD7eN3ihK9P89UbWqE2qT7r5y88l47g/fnRX21X1oW8.jpg","NmTSCbIkb_ie-V4rLG99z1LLwFrtNb0C9qOsTw/XZGOVVFD-Fg.jpg"],"peer_id":-219023505}]"},{"key":"hash","value":"903ebeef9c1a24163852765723f2cede"},{"key":"server","value":"850012"}]}}
09:49:42.088 [main] DEBUG api.longpoll.bots.methods.impl.VkMethod - --> POST https://lp.vk.com/wh219023505?act=a_checkwait=25key=1be1853f70589d346179757d2909c6d95473f006ts=81ts=82 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 76
null : {"error":{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"Unknown error occurred","request_params":[{"key":"method","value":"photos.saveMessagesPhoto"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"v","value":"5.131"},{"key":"photo","value":"[{"markers_restarted":true,"photo":"c6fdd94d21:x","sizes":[],"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"kid":"82e988b3bbfb73e63b83f80762302082","sizes2":[["s","73dc81fbd5359841bcc8485750db278e02bb8fe98677c140e1d6f707","-5032855809629860884",75,75],["m","81a13caa0d81699b8b92bdfd6027a723feea07086c05af56f617748c","-7038935191574522449",130,130],["x","e8fe23611f5b0a924badfea624cc519523caba55f7c5589d8c7d00c4","-332785084712083935",400,400],["o","81a13caa0d81699b8b92bdfd6027a723feea07086c05af56f617748c","-7038935191574522449",130,130],["p","459ec95276a68484db5c611328c03e1d4655ec169fec641bc4fcd6a8","-4687761155108231590",200,200],["q","3f12b4aa8c4b0fb78dde284af4ff3d51b5aa136a93eebe72f3c978ee","8043980158561383550",320,320],["r","3664d209b2246ff89ef95e2b2c6f7dcf52cbc05aed35bd02f6a3ac4f","6410948086168719709",400,400]],"urls":[],"urls2":["c9yB-9U1mEG8yEhXUNsnjgK7j-mGd8FA4db3Bw/7EtAbU60J7o.jpg","gaE8qg2BaZuLkr39YCenI_7qBwhsBa9W9hd0jA/r1U0tbytUJ4.jpg","6P4jYR9bCpJLrf6mJMxRlSPKulX3xVidjH0AxA/IR4wh7q1Yfs.jpg","gaE8qg2BaZuLkr39YCenI_7qBwhsBa9W9hd0jA/r1U0tbytUJ4.jpg","RZ7JUnamhITbXGETKMA-HUZV7Baf7GQbxPzWqA/Wibm9RC68b4.jpg","PxK0qoxLD7eN3ihK9P89UbWqE2qT7r5y88l47g/fnRX21X1oW8.jpg","NmTSCbIkb_ie-V4rLG99z1LLwFrtNb0C9qOsTw/XZGOVVFD-Fg.jpg"],"peer_id":-219023505}]"},{"key":"hash","value":"903ebeef9c1a24163852765723f2cede"},{"key":"server","value":"850012"}]}}

Попытался отправить картинку документом:

[image: da]

При нажатии на картинку в вк:

[image: вф]

Картинка которую создала программа:

[image: вф]

Comment: Судя по логам, происходит непредвиденная ошибка со стороны vk api. Попробуйте сейчас повторить, может сейчас всё заработает

Comment: Проверил, не работает

Comment: Честно, не понимаю, что здесь не так. vk api отвечает неизвестной ошибкой. Может другие ребята лучше разбираются в проблеме и смогут вам помочь...